# eks reduce cost by just in time deployments

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I have a helm chart that deploys:

- nginx
- windows container (costly in our setup)
- mssql (has PersistentVolumeClaim)

is there an existing solution that can replace the helm chart with a cheap stub when traffic drops to zero for 24hrs and then reverted back to original helm chart when traffic is received (I am okay loosing the first request to a maintenance page to check in 3 minutes)?

Ideally a solution that is generic so I don't need to bake something into our helm charts other than an endpoint for `/should-suspend`

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution for this is using KEDA HTTPScaledObject or knative (felt to heavy for me)

For cronjobs and mssql, I would like to watch a deployment that is managed by  HTTPScaledObject.  However, I haven't found a good solution other than writing my own operator at the moment.